# Doesn't get the values of foreach | PHP, Mysql objects

Tags: php, mysql, object, printing, foreach

I have a problem when I try to echo the values inside the foreach loop.
I want to echo how many people liked each posts.
Here is the query which works perfect:

```
$statusQuery = $conn->query("
        SELECT 
        status.id,
        COUNT(status_likes.id) AS likes,
        GROUP_CONCAT(users.username SEPARATOR '|') AS liked_by
        FROM status

        LEFT JOIN status_likes
        ON status.id = status_likes.status

        LEFT JOIN users
        ON status_likes.user = users.id

        GROUP BY status.id 
    ");
```

Then I save it into an array (`$statuses`) by fetching this mysqli object in a while loop.

```
while($row = $statusQuery->fetch_object()){
        $statuses[] = $row;
    }
```

Just to see it works I printed it as objects:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($statuses,true).'</pre>';
```

Then I got this on my screen:

...

```
[18] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 120
        [likes] => 1
        [liked_by] => Mark
    )

[19] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 121
        [likes] => 1
        [liked_by] => Mark
    )

[20] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 122
        [likes] => 1
        [liked_by] => Mark
    )
```

...

Everything works fine, I got the number of likes as `likes` and the people who liked it as `liked_by`.

But I want to save the likes in a variable to echo it later. I used a foreach loop for this, but didn't work for me:

```
$count_likes = "";
    foreach($statuses as $status){
        $count_likes = '<p>'.$status->likes.' people likes it</p>';
    }
```

I realized that if I just simply echo the `$status->likes` that's work fine but I want to save it into a variable to echo it later here:

```
$statuslist .= '<div id="status_'.$statusid.'" class="status_boxes">
<div>'.$statusDeleteButton.'<p id="status_date"><b>Post: 
</b>'.$postdate.'</p>'.$user_image.'<p 
id="status_text">'.$data.'</p>'.$shareButton.''.$likeButton.'Here I want to 
echo the number of likes:'.$count_likes.'
    </div>'.$status_replies.'
    </div>';
```

But I got this on my screen:

Here I want to echo the number of likes: 0
Here I want to echo the number of likes: 0
Here I want to echo the number of likes: 0
Here I want to echo the number of likes: 0
...

I don't know why I got always 0, when the values in my database and I printed the number of likes before and it should give me 1 and not 0.

**EDIT**:
I want to print the `likes` that I left joined on each post/status.
So I want something like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9PZb.png)

But instead of always getting 0 I want to get the number of likes.
I've already tried it, but didn't work for me:

```
foreach($statuses as $status){
        $statuslist .= '<div id="status_'.$statusid.'" class="status_boxes">
       <div>'.$statusDeleteButton.'<p id="status_date"><b>Post: 
       </b>'.$postdate.'</p>'.$user_image.'<p 
       id="status_text">'.$data.'</p>'.$shareButton.''.$likeButton.'<br 
       />Number of likes: '.$status->likes.'
        </div>'.$status_replies.'
        </div>';
    }
```

Comment: Is `$statuslist` inside your `foreach`, it has to be..

Comment: You shouldn't chain together strings like you do for $statuslist because it's really hard to read/troubleshoot, but you should use string interpolation or Heredocs syntax as it's much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: No that's not but I don't know how to solve that... In the HTML form I echo the statuslist `<div id="statusarea"> <?php echo $statuslist; ?></div>`. I tried to put in in a foreach but doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly do you want to be printed for the example data you have shown? Can you edit your question and add the desired output?

Comment: if your `$statuses` is an array `count($statuses)` should be fine to get the count of likes

Comment: So should I use a for loop?

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<count($statuses); $i++){
 $count_likes = $statuses->likes;
}` does not work. It gives me an error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: i am sorry i misunderstood your question

Comment: No problem, I'll try it.

Comment: I have reviewed your code again and i believe it should work do you have any other logic that surrounds your for loop?

Comment: I suppose in this situation we should avoid for loops. That's more complicated and instead of for we can use foreach which is more comfortable and easier. As I see it, I should print out `$statuslist` inside a foreach loop, but I'm not sure. I stucked here...

Comment: if you have a github repo for your project it would be great if you share it if possible and yes try to echo your item inside the for loop

Comment: https://github.com/eistopious/like_system you can see the code here